# MX Title Control not working with Channel Form entries

Tags: safecracker, url-title, mx-title-control

I've been using the excellent MX Title Control CE to append the epoch seconds to the end of my URL string so that they end up:

mysite.com/jobs/this-is-a-new-job-1528549

It works great through the back end, but when I use Channel Form the url_title is always set to 0.

Does anyone have any experience of getting these two to play nicely together?

I've included a field for the url_title in my Channel Form which is (I think) all I need to do, though the instructions are a little sparse...

Thanks

Comment: hi Joe, I hope it can wait for two more days - needs to make a small fix, but I don't have time till Saturday. I will notify you when it will be ready.

Comment: Hi Max, yes that's no problem - I had a little peak into the code myself but it's way out of my programming league :) thanks again for a great extension. kind regards, Joe

Comment: Hi Max, did you have any luck with the fix? Thanks :)

Comment: I haven't heard anything back from Max so I'm going to throw this out to the community again...

Comment: Hi Joe, if possible can you add your own awnswer or tick my answer? It helps others track down your solution should they have the same issue!

Comment: Ah, I have done - thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else experiences it, I've added a pull request that resolves this issue:

https://github.com/joeczucha/mx-title-control/commit/9b0851146e3edc55442879affd3a6e4e9ff3df63

Answer (score 1):

I see from your [MX Title Control GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-title-control/issues/7) that you've fixed your issue. Nice job mate!

For any other readers the solution, which is a patch Joe submitted is listed here : https://github.com/joeczucha/mx-title-control/commit/9b0851146e3edc55442879affd3a6e4e9ff3df63